# Onclick event not working in IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I am making a PHP webpage for database search using JavaScript (search suggest). I used `div` to show the search suggest items.When the user clicks on this a details page for that item opens. It seems to work fine in Firefox bt it doesnot work on IE.

HTML part:

```
<form method="post" name="searchform" id="searchform">    
  <table class="nostyle" width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="30%">Customer  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="search_customer" id="customer_name" class="input-text" onKeyUp="searchsuggest();"  autocomplete="off"/>
    <br /><div id="search_suggest" onclick="document.getElementById('searchform').submit();"> </div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Please help me, I'm a newbie!

Comment: Do you have any errors in the IE Javascript console?

Comment: Do you have any contents in your `<div>`?  It may be so small that you aren't actually clicking on it.  Are you able to log any messages to the console that would indicate your event is firing?

Comment: it works fine in firefox and chrome.... Not working on IE7!

Comment: @JustinWood I'm using IE7

Comment: you can get IE7 developer tools: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now... I changed my javascript

```
var search_suggest = document.getElementById(customer_name);
search_suggest.onclick = function(){ document.getElementById('searchform').submit();
```

Tried doing it with jQuery bt still did not work and don't know why IE did not work with my previous code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an **ONCLICK** event. `type=submit` already does this for you, but the element needs to be an `input`, not a `div`.

Comment: I dont want to use a button for submit... is there another way to do it without using `input` tag?

Comment: Then please describe what you DO want.

Comment: submit the form when suggestion in `div` is clicked... like in Google search.

Comment: Google search uses a <button>, not a <div>.

Comment: I mean like when you enter something in search text box the suggestions appear below an when you click on one of them it shows the results.

Comment: Yes It already does that... I need to submit the form from `div`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/LM4Sg/1/ you can click on the click here in ie and it works.  If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/LM4Sg/ you can click around the screen and never hit the EMPTY div.

You need to put something in it to click.

```
<div id="search_suggest" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('searchform').submit();">Click Here</div>
```

If you just want to leave the space between the div tags use an & nbsp; instead, this also makes it so you can click in ie.  See the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LM4Sg/4/

```
<div id="search_suggest" onclick="alert('searchform');">&nbsp;</div>
```

(changed to use an alert to simplify things.)

Comment: The error you get when you click it is expected, since I just copied your code out of context.  But it demonstrates that the onclick is working.

Comment: It shows the customer name on the `div` if that's what you mean by something in it to click

Comment: The div with the onclick is empty.  The customer name input comes before the div.  Are you wanting the form to submit when they click the word 'Customer'?

Comment: The div gets populated when we enter some words with the suggetions for the search..like in google... I want the form to submit when one of the suggetions is clicked

Comment: the `div` gets populated with content like this (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) so the 'div' goes over the form

Comment: I guess the point is, if you try those jsfiddles in ie you'll see that the onclick, as you have implimented it, works with content in the div.  So if it's not working with dynamic content that's a different question.  But I'd be happy to talk more about it in a chat if we can sync up our schedules.

Comment: I don't have enough reputations for chat(I'm not able to open chat)..but thanks for your help!